# Ionic tab finishes displaying before data loads in

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a favourites section for a vouchers app. I retrieve the current user's favourite vouchers and display them using ngFor in the HTML. However, the very first time I open the favourites tab, the vouchers do not display. However, if I go to another tab then return, it displays. After I have done this once, it continues to display straight away even if I go to other tabs and return. Only once I restart my app will the issue occur again. I am wondering how I can ensure the vouchers to display the first time.

I put the extraction of the favourites vouchers in an ionViewWillEnter() function.

TS

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.http.get('http://xxxx.com/api/users').subscribe((data: any)=>{
      this.users=data["data"]
    })

    this.authService.user().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.user = user;
      } 
    );
    this.getFavourites()
}
getFavourites(){
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<this.users.length;i++){ //Check all users for current user
      if(this.users[i].first_name === this.user.first_name){
        this.favourites = this.users[i].getfavourites //extract array of favourited vouchers
      }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item lines="none"  *ngFor="let favourite of favourites">
      <ion-label> 
        <a routerLink="/details" routerDirection="forward" (click)="openDetails(favourite)"><img class="voucher_image" `enter code here`src='http://xxxx.com/imgs/vouchers/{{favourite.image}}'></a>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

UPDATE: Fixed code based off Sergey's Solution

TS

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.ionViewWillEnter()
 })
}

async ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.http.get('http://wuiske.com/api/usersall').subscribe((data: any)=>{
   this.users=data
  })
   this.user = await this.authService.user().toPromise();
   this.getFavourites()
}
```

Comment: Hey, so do you mean you want the page to only load when data has actually been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your getFavorites() method relies on a few data sources that you are trying to obtain in parallel in async, so that once they finish their execution your call to getFavorites() was already made. Meaning basically that your two async calls inside ionViewWillEnter finish **after** you call getFavorites().

It seems like you are using Observables in your code so you should be able to do something like this:

```
async ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.users = await this.http.get('http://xxxx.com/api/users').toPromise();
    this.user = await this.authService.user().toPromise();
    this.getFavourites()

}
```

Also this lifecycle hook (ionViewWillEnter) is not the best to initiate data acquisition calls, since it originates with transition animation and not at class instantiation time. Ideally you want to use ngOnInit() or maybe even request data from within constructor method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I played around with your solution and got it to work with a similar change.